# Youtube: Get countries of subscribers

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm new to the YouTube API. It's easy to get the subscribers of a channel via Youtube API.
But is there a way to get the subscribers of a channel with country information?
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do so by using Analytics API

For available reports, you can check 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports#Channel_Reports'